# Intelligent use of shouldComponentUpdate to help browser stay responsive

Tags: reactjs

I have a realtime application that gets lots of data. As a result, during lot of handing of the data, the browser becomes unresponsive. I am researching using `Promises`, or `Rx`, but those seem to involve more surgery than I want to commit to at this point.

I read that `shouldComponentUpdate` can be used for this purpose. Would say using it to update once a second be possible [smart is probably what I am looking for] and what would the code look like inside `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {  
        var stocks = {};

        feed.onChange(function(stock) {

            stocks[stock.symbol] = stock;
            this.setState({stocks: stocks, bid: stock, ask: stock, last: stock, type: stock, undsymbol: stock});
        }.bind(this));

        return {
            stocks: stocks            
        };
    },  
    componentDidMount() {              
        var props = this.props;

    },
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
       // What code would go in here to render 
       // all changes, say every 1 second only?
    },
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible?  Yes.  Best practice?  Probably not.

[`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) should return a boolean: `true` if a new update/render cycle is to be run, `false` if not.

one way to throttle rendering using `shouldComponentUpdate` is to do timestamp comparisons:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  const now = Date.now();

  if (!this.lastUpdated || now - this.lastUpdated > 1000) {
    this.lastUpdated = now;

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: yeah I am having second thoughts https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.nbjjxr4il